# Why can Scholze define a tensor product on $D(\operatorname{CondAb})$?

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories

In the paragraph above Warning 2.8 of https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Condensed.pdf , Scholze remarks that you can use the fact that $\operatorname{CondAb}$ has enough projectives to define a tensor product $\otimes^L$ on $D(\operatorname{CondAb}).$ But I was under the impression that having enough projectives only allows you to take a projective resolution of a complex which has vanishing cohomology in high degree, e.g. we can define $\otimes^L : D(\operatorname{CondAb}) \times D^-(\operatorname{CondAb})\to D(\operatorname{CondAb}).$ But Scholze seems to write that it applies to the entire derived category. Can you still get projective resolutions even when the cohomology does not vanish in higher degree? What is Scholze doing to define the tensor product?

Comment: See [here](http://www.numdam.org/item/CM_1988__65_2_121_0.pdf)